# Sed: Match, remove and replace in one sed call

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, split

Let's say I have an string like:

```
Image.Resolution=1024x768,800x600,640x480,480x360,320x240,240x180,160x120,1280x720
```

I would like to use `sed` to remove the first part (`Image.Resolution=`) and then split the rest by comma so I can put all the resolutions in a bash array.

I know how to do it in two steps (two `sed` calls) like:

`sed 's/Image.Resolution=//g' | sed 's/,/ /g'`.

But as an exercise, I'd like to know if there's a way of doing it in one shot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `;` between the commands:

```
sed 's/Image.Resolution=//g; s/,/ /g'
```

From `info sed`:

```
3 `sed' Programs
****************

A `sed' program consists of one or more `sed' commands, passed in by
one or more of the `-e', `-f', `--expression', and `--file' options, or
the first non-option argument if zero of these options are used.  This
document will refer to "the" `sed' script; this is understood to mean
the in-order catenation of all of the SCRIPTs and SCRIPT-FILEs passed
in.

   Commands within a SCRIPT or SCRIPT-FILE can be separated by
semicolons (`;') or newlines (ASCII 10).  Some commands, due to their
syntax, cannot be followed by semicolons working as command separators
and thus should be terminated with newlines or be placed at the end of
a SCRIPT or SCRIPT-FILE.  Commands can also be preceded with optional
non-significant whitespace characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` can also work:

```
s='Image.Resolution=1024x768,800x600,640x480,480x360,320x240,240x180,160x120,1280x720'
awk -F '[=,]' '{$1=""; sub(/^ */, "")} 1' <<< "$s"
1024x768 800x600 640x480 480x360 320x240 240x180 160x120 1280x720
```

Comment: Actually this is a great idea, and I'm going to do it this way (well, kinda... `$(awk -F '[=,]' '{$1=""; sub(/^[0-9]{1,}x[0-9]{1,}/, "")} 1' <<< "$s")` ) because that way I can make sure that the resolutions come in the shape of `[:digit:]x[:digit:]`, but Lev Levitsky answer answers the question better (the way I worded it)

Answer (score 1):

```
x="Image.Resolution=1024x768,800x600,640x480,480x360,320x240,240x180,160x120,1280x720"
x=${x#*=}             # remove left part including =
array=(${x//,/ })     # replace all `,` with whitespace and create array
echo ${array[@]}      # print array $array
```

Output:

1024x768 800x600 640x480 480x360 320x240 240x180 160x120 1280x720

Answer (score 1):

For this concrete example you can do it in short way:

```
sed 's/[^x0-9]/ /g'
```

and

```
x='Image.Resolution=1024x768,800x600,640x480,480x360,320x240,240x180,160x120,1280x720'
y=(${x//[^x0-9]/ })
```

will remove everything execpt `x` and digits `0-9`, so output (or array `y`) is

```
1024x768 800x600 640x480 480x360 320x240 240x180 160x120 1280x720
```